# Showing message based on selected answer from select field

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms, wtforms

I was wondering if anyone knew how to show a message on the web page based on what is chosen in the select field.  For example, in the database for the selections in the select field, each item has a id, name and finish attribute.

If orange is selected from the select drop down, I was wondering how one would go about showing the finish attribute of the orange on the page. And this is to be done without hitting submit.   I use sql-alchemy for the database and Flask-WTF for the forms.

Comment: Seems like ajax call will do the job.

Comment: understood. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

As per the comment you need to:

1) Code a Javascript event function to activate on select field change

2) Make that Javascript function call a Flask API route via Ajax which returns the database information.

3) Dynamically update your page with Javascript based on the returned values.

Personally I like Vue.js as a javascript framework. Google Flask-Ajax - I think Miguel Grinberg has some good tutorials and example code on this stuff.

Comment: Thank you kind sir

Comment: Hi, I've been having trouble finding a tutorial for this sort of thing do you think you can point me in the right direction?

Comment: Look at this tutorial from the point `Ajax From the Server`: https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-xiv-ajax. It is not precisely what you want but it demonstrates the client/server interaction with a flask API to request and get data. Learning to dynamically update your page with Javascript I would suggest looking at some of the documentation on Vue.js to understand the concept and then google around. This is a fairly common usage pattern